# fill radiobutton with data from data base in mvc 4 without using model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

code in controller : this action get data from database and fill (classlist) with this data

```
public ActionResult GetClassListForTeacher()
        {
            List<string> classlist = null;
            ProfileEntities pe= new ProfileEntities();
            string uID = HttpContext.Session["NID"].ToString();
            int year = 2011;
            //int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int session = set_session();
            if (session == 1)//teacher
            {
                classlist = (from c in pe.CLASSES
                                 join lc in pe.LESSON_CARDS
                                 on new { EDUSTG_CODE = c.EDUSTG_CODE, STATISTICAL_CODE = c.STATISTICAL_CODE, FIRST_YEAR = c.FIRST_YEAR,
                                 GRD_CODE = c.GRD_CODE , OCF_CODE = c.OCF_CODE , CLS_SN = c.CLS_SN} 
                                 equals new { EDUSTG_CODE  = lc.EDUSTG_CODE, STATISTICAL_CODE = lc.STATISTICAL_CODE_BELONGS_TO, FIRST_YEAR = lc.FIRST_YEAR,
                                 GRD_CODE = lc.GRD_CODE , OCF_CODE = lc.OCF_CODE_BELONGS_TO , CLS_SN = lc.CLS_SN}
                                 where (lc.NID == uID && lc.FIRST_YEAR_HAVE == year)
                                 select c.NAME
                                ).ToList();
            }
            if (session == 2)//student
            {}
            return Json(classlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And this code in view

```
<div class="dialog-fluid" id="MoreOptionModal" style="display: none; height: 300px; overflow: scroll;" title="Options">
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="block-fluid">
            <div class="row-form">
                <div class="span12">
                    <table style="border: 0;">
                        <tr>        
                            <td style="border: 0;">@Html.RadioButton("type","Friendes",false,new { id = "Friendes"})</td>               
                            <td style="border: 0;"><label>All Friendes</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 0;">@Html.RadioButton("type","Teachers",false,new { id = "Teachers"})</td>               
                            <td style="border: 0;"><label>All Teachers As Friends</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 0;"></td>
                            <td style="border: 0;">@Html.RadioButton("type","Same School",false,new { id = "Same_School" })</td>
                            <td style="border: 0;"><label>Same School</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 0;"></td>
                            <td style="border: 0;">@Html.RadioButton("type","Other School",false,new { id = "Other_Schools"})</td>
                            <td style="border: 0;"><label>Other School</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 0;">@Html.RadioButton("type","Schoolmates",false,new { id = "Schoolmates"})</td>               
                            <td style="border: 0;"><label>All Students As Friends</label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want add list of radio buttons after last radio button which called (Schoolmates)
and this is the code in js

```
 $("#MoreOptionModal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
 });

    $("#options").live("click", function () {
        debugger;
        $("#MoreOptionModal").dialog('open');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Mail/GetClassListForTeacher",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
            }
            });

  });
```

the problem is i already have model in my view and i retrieve data from database and i want to show it my view

Comment: you have to add the element via JavaScript, for example with jquery append method. You have tu put the script code in the success function in the Ajax request.

Comment: OK i understand what you say but how in code @CarlosCorralCarvajal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to success function, of course you have to adapt the solution to your needs, but basically this is the workaround.

```
$.each(result, function(i, name){
    var trToAppend="
    <tr>
       <td style="border: 0;"><input type='radio' name='type' id='" + name + "'/></td>               
       <td style="border: 0;"><label>" + name + "</label></td>
    </tr>
    ";
    $('table').append(trToAppend);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

code in js

```
$("#options").live("click", function () {
        debugger;
        $("#MoreOptionModal").dialog('open');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Mail/GetClassListForTeacher",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#ForTest").val(result);
                var d = $("#ForTest").val().split(",");
                for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                    //alert(d[i])
                    var trToAppend="<tr><td><input type='radio' name='type' id='" + d[i] + "'/></td><td><label>" + d[i] + "</label></td></tr>";
                    $("#MyTest").append(trToAppend);
                }
            }
            });
  });
```

and i add this line in view

```
<input id="ForTest" type="hidden" />
```

i take the list then i split it then i append the html